# How can save the data into database in python django which in list form and list is collection of dictionaries?

Tags: python, django, database

Hello everyone I am beginner in python django framework and I am stucked in the program please help me. Thanks in Advance.
Problem:
I am fetching data using requests method and containing every data in dict form and then append it to the list.
Now i want to save all the data of the dict into the database as per my models
but here I am unable to do that please help me.
here is my models code

```
    class Question(models.Model):
        question_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        question_tag = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        question_url = models.URLField(max_length=300)
        question_view_count = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
        question_answer_count = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.question_title
```

Here is my views.py file to search the question and save it to database
In views.py i am storing data in list which is coming in dict form so basically data is in dict form so how can i perform a loop by which data save into database according to my models.py from the dict form.

```
    def questionSearch(request):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            question_title = request.GET.get('title',)
            question_tag = request.GET.get('tag',)
        url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/' + f'2.2/search/advanced? 
              order=desc&sort=activity&q={question_title}&accepted=False&answers=1&tagged= {question_tag}&site=stackoverflow'
        resp = requests.get(url)
        resp = resp.json()
        questions = []
        question_data = {}
        for i in resp["items"]:
            if i["is_answered"]:
                question_data = {
                    'question_url': i["link"],
                    'question_title': i["title"],
                    'question_tag': i["tags"],
                    'question_view_count': i["view_count"],
                    'question_answer_count': i["answer_count"]
                }
            questions.append(question_data)
        total = []
        for item in questions:
            for key in item.keys():
                total.append(item[key])
                question = Question()
                for i in total:
                    question.question_url = i
                    question.question_title = i
                    question.question_tag = i
                    question.question_view_count = i
                    question.question_answer_count = i  
                question.save()

        context = {
            'questions': questions,
            }

        return render(request, 'stackAPI/index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would define a method in the model to receive data from the dict:

```
class Question(models.Model):
        question_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        question_tag = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        question_url = models.URLField(max_length=300)
        question_view_count = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
        question_answer_count = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

        def from_dict(self, item):
            self.question_title = item["question_title"]
            self.question_tag = item["question_tag"]
            self.question_url = item["question_url"]
            self.question_view_count = item["question_view_count"]
            self.question_answer_count = item["question_answer_count"]

        def __str__(self):
            return self.question_title
```

and use it in the view:

```
       for item in questions:
           question = Question()
           question.from_dict(item)
           question.save()
```

Best regards.